# Simple PHP stuff : variable evaluation

Tags: php, variables, evaluate

OK, I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I don't know the keyword to search for it. The situation is :

```
$sentence = ' $subject is a genius ';
$subject = " Einstein ";
echo( $sentence );
```

How can I make it echo "Einstein is a genius" but keep defining variables $sentence before defining $subject ?

You might realize that this is the basic concept of using template. Yes, I'm trying to achieve it. Thanks guys

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa : Note the order in which the variables have been declared.

Comment: "variable interpolation" can be what you need - as long as it's in the correct order (declared before using).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `sprintf`:

```
$sentence = '%s is a genius';
$subject  = 'Einstein';
echo sprintf($sentence, $subject);
```

This will output `Einstein is a genius`

Comment: OK, your solution did the trick. But can you give me an advice on applying it to real application template? The format of $sentence must be pretty complicate to be a good template.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sentence = '$subject is a genius';
$output = str_replace('$subject', ' Einstein ', $sentence);
echo( $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the concatenator `.`, this "pastes" strings together.

```
$sentence = "is a genius.";
$subject = "Einstein";

echo $subject." ".$sentence;
```

Or do you mean this perhaps? Not quite getting what you mean by "evaluate it later".

```
$sentence = "is a genius.";
$subject = "Einstein";

$fullsentence = $subject." ".$sentence;

echo $fullsentence;
```

**edit** I think you're looking for Frietkot his answer ;)

Comment: sorry, I meant to keep the variable $sentence as it is, but I want to evaluate it later, not at the line I defined it.

Comment: Just imagine you define the template first ($sentence) & the runtime variable later. And template as long as I can't concatenate it like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sentence = "is a genius.";
$subject = "Einstein";


echo '"'. $subject." ".$sentence .'"';
```

Answer (score -2):

change the order of the variable and put a double quote on sentence string
variable does not get evaluated in single quote

```
$subject = " Einstein ";
$sentence = " $subject is a genius ";
echo( $sentence );
```

Comment: Reread the question.  OP wants to be able to set up strings as templates and fill in the values later.